# How to retrieve a particular number from the string XXXX-XXXX-XXX-XXXX through SQL

Tags: sql, regex, string, oracle

I have a column that gets value in the format "100-02-000-020-000-99801-000-000000-000000"

```
INTERNAL_ADDRESS_LINE
-------------------------------------------
100-02-010-020-000-99801-000-000000-000000
150-01-020-000-210-99802-000-000000-000000
150-01-030-000-230-99802-000-000000-000000
```

I want to retrieve the 3rd value (after the second `-`) and 4th value (after third `-`), for example:

```
OUTPUT_COL    COL2
------------------
010           020
020           000
030           000
```

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your strings have a fixed format, I would recommend string functions, since they can get the job done, and are more efficient than regexes:

```
select
    substr(INTERNAL_ADDRESS_LINE, 8, 3) output_col,
    substr(INTERNAL_ADDRESS_LINE, 12, 3) col2
from mytable
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=6402ac2aef11eea8853029b2b31696e0)**:

```
with mytable as (
    select '100-02-010-020-000-99801-000-000000-000000' INTERNAL_ADDRESS_LINE from dual
    union all select '150-01-020-000-210-99802-000-000000-000000' from dual
    union all select '150-01-030-000-230-99802-000-000000-000000' from dual
)
select
    substr(INTERNAL_ADDRESS_LINE, 8, 3) output_col,
    substr(INTERNAL_ADDRESS_LINE, 12, 3) col2
from mytable
```

```
OUTPUT_COL | COL2
:--------- | :---
010        | 020 
020        | 000 
030        | 000
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `regexp_substr()`:

```
select regexp_substr(INTERNAL_ADDRESS_LINE, '[0-9]+', 1, 3),
       regexp_substr(INTERNAL_ADDRESS_LINE, '[0-9]+', 1, 4)
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=cd44f3f2405bb819d31259b7e9153783) is a db<>fiddle.

Note that this assumes that all the non-dash characters are numbers.  A more general version just uses the delimiters:

```
select regexp_substr(INTERNAL_ADDRESS_LINE, '[^-]+', 1, 3),
       regexp_substr(INTERNAL_ADDRESS_LINE, '[^-]+', 1, 4)
```